# When to use non-comparison sorting over comparison sorting

Tags: algorithm, sorting

In class we learned about a bunch of new non-comparison sorts for the sake of avoiding the lower bound of `omega(nlogn)` for all comparison based sorts. But what was a  bit unclear to me was the pro's and con's to when to use which family of sorting algorithms.

Can't any data set be tweaked so that non-comparison sorting algorithms (radix, bucket, key-indexed) can be used? If so, what's the point of comparison sorts even existing?

Sorry for this being such a rudimentary question, but I really can't find anything online.

Comment: By choosing a particular sorting algorithm you trade memory for speed and vice versa. The constraints of your problem make certain algorithms impractical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every set of items can be tweaked to be used in non-comparison sorts in an efficient way. For example, sorting arbitrary precision numbers would require running the loop inside the bucket sort many times, killing the performance.

The problem with radix sorts of the world is that they must examine every element of every item being sorted. Comparison-based sorts, on the other hand, can skip a fair number of sub-elements (digits, characters, etc.) For example, when a comparison function checks two strings, it stops at the first difference, skipping the tails of both strings. Bucket sort, on the other hand, must examine all characters in every string<sup>*</sup>.

In general, chasing the best asymptotic complexity is not always a good strategy: the value of N where using a significantly more complex algorithm pays off is often too high to make the more complex algorithms practical. For example, quicksort has very bad worse time complexity, yet on average it beats most other algorithms hands down due to its very low overhead, making it a good choice in most practical situations.

---

<sup>*</sup> In practice implementations of bucket sort avoid the need to look at all sub-elements (digits, characters, etc.) by switching to a comparison-based sort as soon as the number of items in a bucket drops below a certain threshold. This hybrid approach beats both a plain comparison-based sort and a plain bucket sort.

Comment: Surely bucketsort works from MSD to LSD, and uses some other sort (say insertion sort) when the buckets get small enough. So if you use it to sort strings, it probably only reads the first few bytes of each string. Most quicksort implementations, unless specifically oriented to sorting strings, do not perform this optimization, and at the deeper recursions of quicksort, the compared strings' first difference is progressively deeper in the string. So, although I agree with your overall conclusion, I'm not convinced by the example.

Comment: @rici That's an excellent comment, thank you very much! I agree, my quicksort example is a little misleading, because I brought it in to illustrate a generalized point that is not directly related to the original question - specifically, that low-overhead algorithms with higher asymptotic complexity can beat algorithms that are better asymptotically but have much higher overhead. I edited the answer to reflect your note about switching to merge sort when buckets get small.

Comment: (1) Stopping bucket sort once the buckets have size 1 is often much better than switching to a comparison-based sort.  If you do this, you do fewer, not more, character comparisons if you're sorting strings.  (2) Quicksort isn't a very good example of bad worst-case time complexity not mattering; a good implementation of mergesort does fewer comparisons even on average and is just about as nice to the cache.  Unfortunately, quicksort has a fast reputation that isn't borne out by fast performance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with non-comparison sorting is that their complexity is usually dependent on other parameters than the size of an input. Radix sort, for instance, has O(kn) complexity, where k is the highest number of digits in an element - the question is, how does k relate to n. If k is about the same as n, the algorithm becomes O(n^2).

Comment: Exercise:  If you have n digits in your numbers, how long does a digit-by-digit comparison take in the worst case?  If you do n log(n) of these comparisons, how long does your sort take in the worst case?

Comment: Comparing two numbers that don't exceed the ALU bus/register size should be O(1). Assuming that CMP takes 1 clock tick, and that our ALU  bus/register size is at least as long as the biggest number (which we usually do in analysis of algorithms), the sort you mention takes O(nlogn). Radix sort, on the other hand, does the digit-by-digit comparison explicitly, so it has to call CMP n times,  and since processor is synchronized by a clock, it doesn't help that the numbers in question are at most 4 bits.

Comment: Sorting words is a very special case.  Radix sort takes O(n*k), where k is the word size divided by the highest tolerable radix.  This will grow considerably more slowly than n log(n) does; I should always be willing to choose k around the log of the word size and have wordsize / log wordsize buckets in each pass.  (Except possibly for very, very small sorts relative to the word size, when I might want to do insertion or bubble sort instead.)

Answer (score 1):

Non-comparison based sorting algorithms make assumptions about the input. All elements of the input are required to fall within a range of constant length in order to ensure linear time complexity. On the other hand comparison based sorting algorithms make no assumption about the input and are able to address any case. Non-comparison based sorting algorithms often come at the expense of extra memory cost and the lack of generality of the input.

Comment: Can u give an example of a dataset of keys and values where non-comparison sorting will not work? Can't any dataset be tweaked so the keys are tailored to fit for non-comparison sorting?

Comment: Let's say we want to sort N integers, whose range is not known. In this case we can only use comparison based algorithm. In other words, general sorting problems may only be solved in O(NlgN) time no matter how hard you tweak the input.

Comment: All elements of the input need to fall within a small range in order to ensure O(n log(n)) time complexity of a comparison sort since you call the comparator Theta(n log(n)) times.

Answer (score 1):

You use comparison-based sorting when you're too lazy to write up a non-comparison based sort.

Comparison-based sorts are inherently slower; they need to call a comparator on input elements a whole bunch of times and each call gives the comparison-based sort exactly one bit of information.  A correct comparison-based sort *must* accumulate log_2(n!) ~= n log(n) bits of information about its input on average.

Now, all data has a representation in the machine.  You can tailor a sorting algorithm to your particular kind of data, the representation it has, and the machine you're using to sort, and, if you know what you're doing, you will often beat the pants off any comparison-based sorting algorithm.

However, performance isn't everything, and there are cases (most cases I've seen, in fact) where the most performant solution isn't the right solution.  Good comparison-based sorts can take a black-box comparator and they *will* sort the input in a small constant times n log(n) comparisons.  And that's good enough for almost all applications.

**EDIT**:  The above only really applies for *internal sorting*, where you have more than enough RAM to store the whole input.  External sorting (overflowing to a disk, say) should usually be done by reading about half a RAMful of data at a time, using a non-comparison-based sort, and writing the sorted result out.  All the while being careful to overlap sorting with input and output.  At the end, you do a (comparison-based) n-way merge.

Comment: Hey, you aren't [tmuklebu on TopCoder](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=MemberProfile&cr=8547850), are you?

Comment: I am indeed tmyklebu on TopCoder.

Comment: I knew I saw this handle somewhere :)